# Switching between readline editing-modes in GNU octave

Tags: readline, octave

When punching away at the keyboard on the octave command line, I sometimes find that the various readline shortcuts stop working, e.g. `C-a` and `C-e` just insert `^A` and `^E`.

It took me a while to realize that this is because I've accidentally switched to vi-editing-mode, and indeed there's is a `toggle-editing-mode` (`C-M-j`) documented in an [old version](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/octave/octave_34.html) of the octave manual.

My question is, how do I return to emacs-mode? I can't find any shortcut listed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much web-searching and manipulation of `~/.inputrc`, I accidentally found that **`C-e`** in **vi-command mode** actually does the trick and executes `emacs-editing-mode`. This is discussed  in [this posting](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/), but with regards to bash, they must be related somehow, but I can't find how by looking in the octave sources.

Knowing what to look for also allowed me to find, one way to change this binding through `~/.inputrc`:

```
$if mode=emacs
  set keymap vi

  "\e\C-j":   emacs-editing-mode
  "\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file

  set keymap emacs
$endif
```

Anyway, seems I should be reading `readline.info` and perhaps also `history.info`.

#### Edit

Added `C-M-j` as a vi binding to switch back to emacs, in addition to the default `C-e`. Also added a vi-binding to re-read `~/.inputrc`.